# Error : aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the max of column:

```
select * from
( select col1, count(*) as cnt from talbe1
group by col1
) dt
where cnt = max(cnt)
```

I tried to get exact value and it worked such as:

```
where cnt = 5
```

or

```
where cnt > 3
```

that was OK so what is wrong with the first query?

Edit: the numbers I put there (5, 3) are completely random, I want to get the maximum number of cnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate clauses have to go in the `HAVING` section.  However, this won't work with your query as is.  What you probably wanted to do was:

```
select top 1 col1, count(*) as cnt 
from talbe1
group by col1
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `HAVING` clause. For example if you want to get `cnt=3` records

```
Select col1, count(*) as cnt from talbe1
Group by col1
Having count(*)=3
```

If you want to get `MAX(cnt)`

```
Select Top(1) col1, count(*) as cnt from talbe1
Group by col1
Order by cnt desc
```

Comment: this is just return the 3 count not the MAX??

Comment: @Star I think that is what he is trying to get as per OP

Comment: No I'm the OP, sorry maybe I didn't enplane my question well,  
anyway thanks.

Comment: @Star: So, you down voted me for confusion and helping you? Great ! thanks

Comment: It's not about the vote, it's about the other answers, 
which gives the needed results and are not compatible with your answer , that got more votes. just clarification no hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution,
it was pretty simple:(I should have focused more)

```
select max(cnt) from
( select Fld301, count(*) as cnt from TbC3
group by Fld301
) dt
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this query:

```
select * from
(
    select 
        col1, 
        count(*) as cnt, 
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS ran 
    from talbe1 
    group by col1
) dt
where ran=1
```